# How do I set the following browser console commands to automatically run on startup?

Tags: firefox

I want to learn how to set the following browser console commands to run automatically at startup.

```
Services.env.set("XPCSHELL_TEST_PROFILE_DIR", "");
Cc["@mozilla.org/security/certoverride;1"].getService(Ci.nsICertOverrideService).setDisableAllSecurityChecksAndLetAttackersInterceptMyData(true);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't see how this could get any more clear.